# Minimising the ratio of distances from points to a line

Tags: geometry

'Given a line and two distinct points A and B on the same side of the line, find the point P on the line such that AP/PB is minimised.'

I am completely stumped by this question. It doesn't seem doable for some locations of A and B. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Because the question talks about the *"side of a line"*, we know this is a 2D problem.

Without loss of generality, you can rotate and translate the system so that the line is on the $x$ axis. This means 
$$\begin{array}{l} P = (x_P ,\, 0) \\ A = (x_A ,\, y_A) \\ B = (x_B ,\, y_B) \end{array} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
the distance $AP$ is
$$AP = \sqrt{ (x_P - x_A)^2 + y_A^2 }$$
and the distance $PB$ is
$$PB = \sqrt{ (x_P - x_B)^2 + y_B^2 }$$
and therefore the ratio is
$$\frac{AP}{PB} = \sqrt{ \frac{ (x_P - x_A)^2 + y_A^2 }{ (x_P - x_B)^2 + y_B^2 } } \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$

Let $f(x_P)$ be the ratio. It reaches an extremum when its derivative,
$$\frac{ d f(x_P) }{d x_P} = 2 \frac{ ( x_P^2 (x_A - x_B) + x_P (x_B^2 - x_A^2 + y_B^2 - y_A^2) - x_A (x_B^2 + y_B^2) + x_B (x_A^2 + y_A^2) ) } { \left ( (x_P - x_B)^2 + y_b^2 \right)^2 }$$
is zero.

---

It turns out (using e.g. Maple or Sage) that the solution to $d f(x_P) / d x_P = 0$ is
$$x_P = \frac{ (x_B^2 + y_B^2) - (x_A^2 + y_A^2) }{ 2 (x_B - x_A) } \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{ \left( 1 + \frac{(y_A + y_B)^2}{(x_A - x_B)^2} \right) \left( (x_A-x_B)^2 + (y_A-y_B)^2 \right )}$$

If we use $x = \frac{x_P - x_A}{x_B - x_A}$, so that $x_P = x_A + x ( x_B - x_A)$, $x = 0$ corresponds to $x_P = x_A$, and $x = 1$ corresponds to $x_P = x_B$. Then, the solution is
$$x = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{y_B - y_A}{x_B - x_A} \frac{y_B + y_A}{x_B - x_A} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \left( 1 + \left ( \frac{y_B + y_A}{x_B - x_A} \right)^2 \right ) \left ( 1 + \left ( \frac{y_B - y_A}{x_B - x_A} \right)^2 \right ) }$$

---

Let $K$ be the slope of $\overline{AB}$ with respect to the line,
$$K = \frac{y_B - y_A}{x_B - x_A} \tag{5}\label{NA5}$$
and $D$ twice the average (mean) distance of $\overline{AB}$ from the line divided by the length of $AB$ projected to the line,
$$D = 2 \frac{1}{2} \frac{y_B + y_A}{x_B - x_A} = \frac{y_B + y_A}{x_B - x_A}\tag{6}\label{NA6}$$
(or alternatively, twice the area between the line and $\overline{AB}$, divided by the squared length of $\overline{AB}$ projected to the line),
then the ratio $\frac{AP}{PB}$ is minimized or maximized at point $P = \left( x_A + x ( x_B - x_A) ,\, 0 \right )$,
$$x = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} K D \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \left ( 1 + D^2 \right ) \left ( 1 + K^2 \right ) } \tag{7}\label{NA7}$$
where $P$ is closest to $A$ at $x = 0$, and closest to $B$ at $x = 1$.

Asymptotically, the ratio tends to 1, of course.
I did verify the result numerically; I find the symmetry wrt. $K$ and $D$ in $x$ very interesting. There is a better description for $D$, but I just cannot find the correct term. (If we were to draw another line parallel to the existing line, leaving $A$ and $B$ on different sides but the same distance from this line, and form a rectangle from these lines with ends being the perpendiculars from $A$ and $B$, then $D$ is the aspect ratio of this rectangle.)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this: let C be the intersection of AB with the line. In case A is between B and C, like in figure:
[image]
Then [BP] $\leq$ [AB] + [AP] ([triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)), with [BP] maximum when P=C.

If [BP]$\leq$([AB]+[AP]) with [AB], [AP] and [BP] positive

$\implies$ 1/[BP]$\geq$1/([AB]+[AP])

$\implies$ [AP]/[BP]$\geq$[AP]/([AB]+[AP]) with equality when P=C.

So [AP]/[PB] is minimum when P=C.

You still have to consider the case when B is between A and C.

Here's an intuition, for the ease of calculation consider the line horizontal and the points A(1,1) and B(2,2) like in the figure:
[image]
Then:

[AP3]/[BP3] = $\sqrt3$/$\sqrt3$ = 1

[AP2]/[BP2] = $\sqrt2$/2 = 1/$\sqrt2$

[AP1]/[BP1] = 1/$\sqrt3$

[AP]/[BP] = $\sqrt2$/$\sqrt8$ = 1/2

So the closer to the intersection point of AB with the line, the smaller the ratio: from 1, to 1/$\sqrt2$ to 1/$\sqrt3$ to minimum 1/2.

Comment: This doesn’t work. Consider the line $y=0$ and points $A=(1,1)$, $B=(2,2)$. $C$ is obviously the origin, but the derivative of $\|(x,0)-A\|/\|(x,0)-B\|$ is equal to $-1/8$ there, so can’t be a local (or global) minimum. How did you conclude that maximizing $[BP]$ minimizes the ratio?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

WLOG, the line is the axis $x$, $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(x,y)$. (Otherwise you can normalize to this representation by applying a similarity transform, which preserves the ratio of distances.)

[image]

Let $P=(t,0)$. Instead of minimizing the ratio, we will maximize the square of its inverse, to avoid the square roots and simplify the expressions.

$$r^{-2}(t)=\frac{(x-t)^2+y^2}{t^2+1}=1+\frac{a-2xt}{t^2+1},$$ where $a=x^2+y^2-1$.

We cancel the derivative on $t$, the numerator of which is

$$-2x(t^2+1)-(a-2xt)2t=2xt^2-2at-2x.$$

The solutions are

$$t=\frac{a\pm{\sqrt{4x^2+a^2}}}{2x}.$$

Remains to discuss which corresponds to a minimum of $r$.

---

Note that the parameters have a simple geometric interpretation in the general case:

- $t$ is the ratio of $P$ between the orthogonal projections of $A\to A',B\to B'$ onto the line,
- $x$ is the ratio $|A'B'|/|AA'|$,
- $d$ is the ratio $|AB|^2/|AA'|^2$ minus $1$.

Comment: Is there any way to give a meaning to the point which corresponds to a minimum of r? most of the solutions seem to involve a lot of heavy algebra but there should be a more geometrically oriented solution.